# Changing global variable mentioned on a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to change global variable from a nested function, the target variable is also mentioned on another global variable, here's the code I used:

```
import requests

codomain = 'line.me'
requ = { "Host": control_domain, "DNT":  "1", "Accept-Language": "*", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Encoding": "*", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1" }

def menu():
    ans=input(" Choose : ")
    if str(ans)=="1":
        ...
        opti=input(" Choose Option :  ")
        if str(opti)=="1":
            def text():

                print("1. Insert Target Domain")
                print("2. Leave it as default")
                print("")
                ansi=input(" Choose Option : ")
                if str(ansi)=="1":
                    codomain=input(" Domain : ")
                    print(f"{codomain}" + " Selected as Domain")
                else:
                    pass

                print(" Outside " + f"{codomain}")
                print(" Check " + f"{requ}")
                r=requests.get("http://linecorp.com",headers=requ)
            text()
menu()
```

Specifically, the problem is located at global variable itself:

```
codomain="line.me"
requ={ "Host": codomain }
```

I want to add user input whether the `codomain` is changed by the user or left as default; which is `line.me`. I have tried to explicitly cast the changed variable using `global` and `nonlocal`.

```
global codomain
codomain=input("Input Domain:")
```

But the above codes doesn't change the target `codomain` inside `requ` variable, this proven when printing the variable:

```
print(codomain) #It prints user-input
print(requ) #Codomain inside requ still prints default line.me
```

I'm trying another workaround by directly accessing `globals` for `codomain` inside `requ`:

```
host="line.me"
codomain=str(globals,["host"])
requ={ "Host": codomain }
```

The following results in `dict` error as probably `dict` can't pass item directly.

Comment: The `requ={ "Host": codomain }` line creates a dictionary that has the *value* of `codomain` in it at the time it's executed. Changing `codomain` afterwards will not affect it.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Shoul've just set it to ```["Host"]=... ``` instead of ```(globals,["Host"])```. Also thanks for the grammar correction part @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, i got a little confused on how the `dict` works. The `dict codomain` variable is reserved and not follows the `codomain` changes. Turns out it's easy to fix.

````
### Instead of accessing ```globals```
codomain=str(globals,["Host"])

### Just change the ```dict``` directly
requ["Host"]=codomain
````